# Phonegap contact photos orientation

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova, orientation, cordova-plugins

I use phonegap 3.6.0 for both Android and iOS application. 
I use Contacts phonegap plugin to retrieve all contacts in my phone, then use their photos (using "photos" property in Contact object). Link to the plugin documentation: 
http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/org.apache.cordova.contacts

In android their is no issue with using it, but with iOS sometimes the contact photo is rotated. I think it depends on what the orientation was when the contact photo was taken. Of course it display well in the iPhone contacts app.

So the problem is that I can't figure out a way to rotate the contact photo. Specifically, there is no orientation flag when gathering the contact photo with the Contacts plugins.

Any helps on this?

Thank you

Comment: I think you should check if device orientation is portrait or landscape  through javascript while fetching contacts. Possibly through device height width

Answer (score 0):

What about simply checking the dimensions of the photo, and if width > height, using CSS to rotate it?

Comment: I can't fix it with CSS, because there are 4 kinds of rotation (depends on 4 states of the image orientation flag). If we detect portrait or landscape via Width & Height, we still don't know if the photo will be upside down or not.

Thanks for any help !